# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/src/public/favicon.ico'

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, favicon

I am trying to get a front end working but I am getting an error message when I use docker-compose. I have created the favicon.ico within the path 'src/public/favicon.ico' and 'serve-favicon' has been installed but I am still getting the same error.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  #fileserver:
  #  image: darrylwest/src-fileserver
  #  volumes:
  #   - ./src:/src
  identitydb:
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    volumes:
     - ./data/redisdb:/data
  service:
    image: node:12.22-alpine
    working_dir: /home/node
    entrypoint: "node ./app/app.js --env production"
    mem_limit: "300M"
    memswap_limit: "1G"
    ports:
     - "13994:13001"
    volumes:
     - .:/home/node # modified here to take into account the new app path
     - ./logs:/home/node/logs
    user: node
    links:
     - identitydb
     #- fileserver
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
     - SERVICE_ROUTE=develop
# networks:
#   default:
#     external:
#       name: nowce-temp-network
networks:
  nowce-temp-network:
    external: true
```

Here is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\darre\NowCE\Projects\nowce-browser\portal-login> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container portal-login-identitydb-1  Created                                                                                  0.0s 
 ✔ Container portal-login-service-1     Created                                                                                  0.0s 
Attaching to portal-login-identitydb-1, portal-login-service-1
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:C 11 Sep 16:42:58.749 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:C 11 Sep 16:42:58.749 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:C 11 Sep 16:42:58.749 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.751 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.751 # Server initialized
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.751 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.751 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.757 * DB loaded from disk: 0.006 seconds
portal-login-identitydb-1  | 1:M 11 Sep 16:42:58.757 * Ready to accept connections
portal-login-service-1     | create log manager for version:  0.90.125
portal-login-service-1     | init passport callbacks...
portal-login-service-1     | create auth0 strategy with params:  {
portal-login-service-1     |   domain: 'nowce.auth0.com',
portal-login-service-1     |   clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
portal-login-service-1     |   clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
portal-login-service-1     |   callbackURL: 'http://local.nowce.com/callback'
portal-login-service-1     | }
portal-login-service-1     | start the app server
portal-login-service-1     | internal/fs/utils.js:269
portal-login-service-1     |     throw err;
portal-login-service-1     |     ^
portal-login-service-1     |
portal-login-service-1     | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/src/public/favicon.ico'
portal-login-service-1     |     at Object.statSync (fs.js:1016:3)
portal-login-service-1     |     at resolveSync (/home/node/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:187:17)
portal-login-service-1     |     at favicon (/home/node/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:61:12)
portal-login-service-1     |     at AppServer.start (/home/node/app/AppServer.js:39:17)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/app.js:17:8)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
portal-login-service-1     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
portal-login-service-1     |   errno: -2,
portal-login-service-1     |   syscall: 'stat',
portal-login-service-1     |   code: 'ENOENT',
portal-login-service-1     |   path: '/src/public/favicon.ico'
portal-login-service-1     | }
portal-login-service-1     |
portal-login-service-1 exited with code 1
```

If anyone has any ideas then please let me know.

Many thanks.